# How to use property with string index?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have this code:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    private
      procedure SetKeyValue(const Key: WideString; Value: Widestring);
      function GetKeyValue(const Key: WideString): WideString;
    public
      // this works
      property KeyValue[const Index: WideString] : WideString read GetKeyValue write SetKeyValue;

      // this does not compile
      // [Error]: Incompatible types: 'String' and 'Integer'
      property Speed: WideString index 'SPEED' read GetKeyValue write SetKeyValue;
  end;
```

The `Speed` property gives me error:

> Incompatible types: 'String' and 'Integer'

I need the index to be string.
Is it possible to use the `index` with string value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible. Indexed properties support Integer as index constants only.

See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Properties#Index_Specifiers) (own emphasis):

> Index specifiers allow several properties to share the same access method while representing different values. An index specifier consists of the **directive `index` followed by an integer constant between `-2147483647` and `2147483647`**. If a property has an index specifier, its `read` and `write` specifiers must list methods rather than fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not possible with an `index` specifier, as it only supports integral indexes. You will have to use a separate set of property getter/setter methods:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    ...
    procedure SetSpeed(const Value: WideString);
    function GetSpeed: WideString;
  public
    ...
    property Speed: WideString read GetSpeed write SetSpeed;
  end;

procedure TMyClass.SetSpeed(const Value: WideString);
begin
  KeyValue['SPEED'] := Value;
end;

function TMyClass.GetSpeed: WideString;
begin
  Result := KeyValue['SPEED'];
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I already know that. but that misses the whole point of the property index if I need to write a setter/getter for every key. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It works very well

**property Values[const Name: string]: string read GetValue write SetValue;**

```
{ClassName=class}
private
 fArrayKey: Array of String;{1}
 fArrayValue: Array of String;{2}
 procedure  Add(const Name, Value: string);
 function GetValue(const Name: string): string;
 procedure SetValue(const Name, Value: string);
published
 property Values[const Name: string{1}]: string{2} read GetValue write SetValue;
```

---

```
function   {ClassName.}GetValue(const Name: string): string;
Var I:integer;
Begin
Result := '#empty';
  for I := low(fArrayKey) to high(fArrayKey) do
    if fArrayKey[i]=Name then
       Begin
         Result := fArrayValue[i];
         Break
       End;
If result='#empty' the Raise Exception.CreateFmt('Key %s not found',[name]);
End;
procedure  {ClassName.}SetValue(const Name, Value: string);
var i,j:integer
Begin
j:=-1;
  for I := low(fArrayKey) to high(fArrayKey) do
    if fArrayKey[i]=Name then
       Begin
         j:= i;
         Break
       End;
If j=-1 then Add(name,value) else fArrayValue[i]:= Value;
End;
procedure  {ClassName.}Add(const Name, Value: string);
begin
  SetLength(fArrayKey,Length(fArrayKey)+1);
  SetLength(fArrayValue,Length(fArrayValue)+1);
  fArrayKey  [Length(fArrayKey)  -1] := Name;
  fArrayValue[Length(fArrayValue)-1] := Value;
end;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Properties_(Delphi)

Comment: That's what OP shown in their `KeyValue` property. Index specifier in Delphi is something different. It allows you to use the same getter and setter for many properties where inside the getter you switch by the index specifier value. So that this "works" and is a possible implementation for index specifier as known by different languages, in Delphi it's not the real index specifier usage. The answer is that you cannot use string type with the index specifier.

Comment: Do you means something like this? http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Index

Comment: Yes, that's the usage of the real index specifier. Many properties use the same getter and setter. In their implementation they receive the index specifier value and they can decide what to do with the value to be get or set. What you've shown is fine, but it doesn't use the index specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
    type
  // Class with Indexed properties
  TRectangle = class
  private
    fCoords: array[0..3] of Longint;
    function  GetCoord(Index: string): Longint;
    procedure SetCoord(Index: string; Value: Longint);
  public
    property Left   : Longint Index 0 read GetCoord write SetCoord;
    property Top    : Longint Index 1 read GetCoord write SetCoord;

    property Right  : Longint Index 2 read GetCoord write SetCoord;
    property Bottom : Longint Index 3 read GetCoord write SetCoord;
    property Coords[Index: string] : Longint read GetCoord write SetCoord;
  end;
  
  const
  IndexCoordMap:array [0..3] of TIdentMapEntry
    (
    (Value: 0;   Name: 'Left'),
    (Value: 1;   Name: 'Top'),
    (Value: 2; Name: 'Right'),
    (Value: 3; Name: 'Bottom')
  );
  
  
  
  implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// TRectangle property 'Getter' routine
function TRectangle.GetCoord(Index: string): Longint;
var IntIndex: Integer;
begin
  // Only allow valid index values
  if (IdentToInt(Index, IntIndex, IndexCoordMap))
  then Result := fCoords[IntIndex]
  else raise Exception.Create('Invalid index');
end;

// TRectangle property 'Setter' routine
procedure TRectangle.SetCoord(Index: string; Value: Integer);
var IntIndex: Integer;
begin
  // Only allow valid index values
  if (IdentToInt(Index, IntIndex, IndexCoordMap))
  then fCoords[IntIndex] := Value
    else raise Exception.Create('Invalid index');
end;
```